How to modify folder columns using Sharepoint API
I have a folder in Sharepoint with a lot of files, and there is 2 columns that I'd like to fill in automatically using Python, as it's not a list I couldn't find how to do that.
I already managed to send the files to the folder using the Office-365 API through Python.
This is how my folder looks (or rather what I'd like to do, only the Name column is full so far):



Name
Number
Version




abc123-1.pdf
123
1


xyz245-4.pdf
245
4



Only thing I could find is how to access the names of the files using:
def folder_details(ctx, folder_relative_path):
    folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_relative_path)
    fold_names = []
    sub_folders = folder.files
    ctx.load(sub_folders)
    ctx.execute_query()
    for s_folder in sub_folders:
        fold_names.append(s_folder.properties['Name'])
    return fold_names

Thank you!

To edit fields you need to work against the listitem, not the file

My problem is that it's not a list but a folder, when I check file properties I can access the name, the time last modified but can't find how to access new  columns @rlv-dan

Files & folders are actually listitems (with a file/folder property). Columns are stored on this listitem.

@RaytheonXie-MSFT Well I did a workaround where I stored the pdf in a folder and created a list where one of the column is actually a link to each pdf. So not really the perfect solution
